# How to stop scrollview at a certain point?

Tags: objective-c, scrollview

I have big images in a vertical scrollview. I want the scrollview to stop at each image, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could enable paging. If you set properly the size of the content of the scroll view it works nice.